# JavaFX and Applet sandbox model

Tags: plugins, applet, javafx-2, ria, intranet

Given the recent panic about web browser Java plug-in security issues, I find the widespread JavaFX enthusiasm a bit peculiar.

I'm not very familiar with entirely Java-based client-side web technologies. I suppose applets are pretty much out of the picture, but shouldn't FX have the same sandbox model security issues when used on the internet?

Is Oracle's JavaFX enthusiasm mainly reserved for intranets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is Oracle's JavaFX enthusiasm mainly reserved for intranets?

No, you can use JavaFX also as standalone application or with Java Web Start.

There are even some native package bundlers.

Comment: Thanks! Guess Oracle's priorities make sense in that case.